# jquery show and hide div issue

Tags: jquery

I have created an editable form that allows users to edit their profile information.
This form can be saved and revisted so I need to be able to save the updates as the user goes along.
This is working ok.

The form is very long so in some sections I have fields that show / hide using jquery depending on the yes or no selections for a previous input.
This also works except that if a radio input is selected and saved whe the form is revisted the jquery has hidden the details field again.

So what I need is some help amending the following jquery code so that if neither radio button is seleced the details div is hidden but if the Yes option is selected and saved it will automatically open when the form is revisted! Thanks

```
$("#diet-details").hide();
$("input[name=diet]").click(function() {
    if ( $("#diet1").attr('checked'))
        $("#diet-details").hide();

    if ( $("#diet2").attr('checked'))
        $("#diet-details").show();
});
```

Comment: You should store your state in session or in localStorage or submit the form with AJAX (but that will also reset the form if you come back to that page, so store your input-states  in any case.)

Comment: `attr('checked')` returns _undefined_.

Comment: Just an FYI as it is "neither radio button is seleced the details div is hidden" - conflicts with your code as #diet1 check hides the area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the show/hide condition to the toggle function, and instead of always hiding the diet-details div in the beginning, check if diet1 option is checked and show it (or hide it) based on that,

```
$(function() {
  $('#diet-details').toggle($("#diet1").is(':checked'));

  $("input[name=diet]").click(function() {
    $('#diet-details').toggle($("#diet1").is(':checked'));
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that would be:

```
(function(){
    var $d1 = $("#diet1"),
        $d2 = $("#diet2"),
        $details = $("#diet-details");

    !$d2.prop('checked') && $details.hide();

    $("input[name=diet]").click(function() {
        $d1.prop('checked') && $details.hide();
        $d2.prop('checked') && $details.show();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to set initial state:

```
function checkem() {
  if ($("#diet1").prop('checked')) $("#diet-details").hide();
  if ($("#diet2").prop('checked')) $("#diet-details").show();
}
$("input[name=diet]").click(function () {
  checkem();
});
checkem(); //sets initial state based one current
```

test fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/YqUhZ/

IF you want it to show if NEITHER is checked then:

```
function checkem() {
  if ($("input[name=diet]:checked").length) {
    $("#diet-details").hide();
  } else {
    $("#diet-details").show();
  }
}
$("input[name=diet]").change(function () {
  checkem();
});
checkem(); //sets initial state based one current
```

Comment: You also probably want the `.change` event